# Complex dplyr group_by filtering

Tags: r, dplyr

I cannot figure out how to write complex filtering criteria on groups in tidyverse. Consider the example dataframe below:

```
df <- tibble(
    a = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3), 
    b = c(1,2,3,1,4,50,5,3),
    c = c("PIZZA", "HAM", NA, "COKE", "LOBSTER", "LOBSTER", NA, NA),
)
```

I want to `a` to be my grouping variable, and then select the record with the largest record in `b` such that the entry in `c` is not `NA`.
Desired output:

```
tibble(
    a = c(1, 2, 3),
    b = c(2, 50, 3),
    c = c("HAM", "LOBSTER", NA)
)
```

I can of course do

```
df %>% group_by(a) %>% filter(b == max(b))
```

but then I don't satisfy the column `c` criterion. Some complications:

1. The number of records between groups is not consistent.
2. If the c record is `NA` for all records in the group, then choose the largest `b` record with `NA`.

Comment: Why not just filter to remove NA values of c, then filter for the max b? Also, `=` is for assignment, `==` is for comparison

Comment: @camille exactly my idea (too fast!), something like `df %>% filter(!is.na(c)) %>% group_by(a) %>% filter(b == max(b))` seems readable and straightforward.

Comment: @camille Sorry, clarified problem. A group might be all NAs, and if so, I still want a record for that group.

Comment: So what would that record be, NA?

Comment: @camille Yes, edited example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the updated example, you can flag groups where `c` is only `NA` to use as a second filtering condition. I'm making this more verbose than it needs to be for the sake of illustration—you probably don't need to keep `all_na` as a variable, for example, just do that calculation inline in the first `filter` call. In this case, amend my original suggestion of filtering for `!is.na(c)` to match that *or* cases where all `c` values are `NA`.

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(a) %>%
  mutate(all_na = all(is.na(c))) %>%
  filter(!is.na(c) | all_na) %>%
  filter(b == max(b))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#> # Groups:   a [3]
#>       a     b c       all_na
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   <lgl> 
#> 1     1     2 HAM     FALSE 
#> 2     2    50 LOBSTER FALSE 
#> 3     3     3 <NA>    TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

We can subset 'b' where there are no NA elements in 'c' after grouping by 'a'

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    group_by(a) %>% 
     slice(if(all(is.na(c))) 1 else which.max(b[!is.na(c)]))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   a [3]
#      a     b c      
#  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>  
#1     1     2 HAM    
#2     2    50 LOBSTER
#3     3     3 <NA>
```

Comment: Added clarification to question that invalidates this answer.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(a) %>%
  filter(b == max(b),
         !is.na(c))
```

Comment: Added clarification to question that invalidates this answer.